# How to find the object type using printf in C?

Tags: c++, oop, class, inheritance, printf

Let's say we have a `Class A`, `Class B` derives from `Class A`, and `Class C` derives from `Class B`.

I create a object of `Class C`, but the pointer is assigned to variable of type A.

```
A *a = new C() ;
```

How do i know, if `a` is of type `Class A`, or `Class B` or `Class C` at run time?

I need to put some debug logs and print the type of the object.

Comment: You could implement a virtual method doing different things in different classes, e.g. printing "I'm an A" or "I'm a C".

Comment: Classes don't exist in C. (So I've edited the tags.)

Answer (score 3):

(Assuming your classes to be polymorphic)The whole point of using dynamic polymorphism is to let the runtime do the needful without knowing the exact type of the object.
Once you start writing code which depends on *type* of the object you are making your code more closely coupled.
However,
If you still want to know the type for whatever reasons you can use **[typeid](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/)** or **[dynamic_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)**.

Comment: Any technical reasoning for the downvote is highly appreciated.

Comment: He said he needs it for debugging. Reflection, and being able to just say `printf("x has class %s\n", x.class())` is a nice feature that is really lacking from C++ (and present in most other object-oriented languages). I didn't downvote you, but I guess the reason is that you did not read the question properly.

Comment: @Zane: You can use `typeid()` in `printf()` to give you that details.I don't see how it does not answer the Q.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a built-in way to determine this. The only option I can think of you have, is to give class *A* a virtual function.

```
class A {
  public:
    virtual int getType() const {
        return 'A';
    }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    virtual int getType() const {
         return 'B';
    }
};
```

I'm sorry for possible type issues. Writing from a smart phone.

Answer (score 1):

If `A` has any virtual functions, you can get a string describing its runtime type using RTTI:

```
A *a = could_return_an_object_of_any_derived_class();

cout << typeid(*a).name();
```

The string returned by `name()` is not guaranteed to be friendly to humans, and can vary between compilers.  All it is guaranteed to be is different between different classes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is what virtual functions are for:

```
struct A
{
    virtual ~A() { }
    virtual char const * name() const { return "Class A"; }
};

struct B : A
{
    virtual char const * name() const { return "Class B"; }
};

struct C : B
{
    virtual char const * name() const { return "Class C"; }
};
```

Now you can say:

```
#include <iostream>

void print_me(A const & x)
{
    std::cout << "I am " << x.name() << ".\n";
}
```

(Or use `a->name()` in your example, but I don't like that example, because usually you shouldn't use naked pointers or `new` in C++.)

Comment: Change `virtual void name()` to `virtual char *name()`.